# cannot access the .id value of a resource

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js

Trying to access $scope.mySlot.id but it is undefined.

```
    $scope.removeMe = function() {                                      
    var shouldRemove = confirm('Remove you from this field trip?');
    if (shouldRemove) {
        var data = null;
        UserService.me().then(function(me){
            var data = {userID: me.id, eventID: tripID}
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        }).then (function(data){ 
            var mySlot = GreenTripFilledSlotsFactory.get(data);
            return mySlot;
        }).then (function(mySlot) {
              $scope.mySlot = mySlot;
              console.log("this is $scope.mySlot: ");
              console.log($scope.mySlot);         //this shows up as a resource with proper values
              console.log("this is $scope.mySlot.id: ")
              console.log($scope.mySlot.id);      //this is undefined
        }).then (function(success){
              return $scope.mySlot.$delete();     // this isn't working'
        }).then(function(success){
            console.log('mySlot deleted');         
            route.reload();
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        })
    }   
};
```

In the console.logs $scope.mySlot is shown as a resource and it does list the values of it. But I'm confused why $scope.mySlot.id is undefined.

FACTORIES:

```
.factory('GreenTripSlotsFactory', ['$resource', function($resource) {   
    return $resource('/api/GreenTripSlots/:id/', {id: '@id' }, {
    update: {method: 'PUT' }
    });
}])
.factory('GreenTripFilledSlotsFactory', ['$resource', 
    function($resource) {  
    return $resource('/api/GreenTripSlots/:userID/:eventID/:slotID', 
    {id: '@id' }, {
    update: {method: 'PUT' }
    });
}])
```

BACKEND contollers:

```
    // = /api/GreenTripSlots/:userID/:eventID
    router.route('/:userID/:eventID')
    .get(function(req,res) {
        procedures.procGetSlotByUserAndTrip(req.params.userID, 
        req.params.eventID).then(function(greenTripUserSlot){
            res.send(greenTripUserSlot);
        }, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.sendStatus(500);

        })
    })

// = /api/GreenTripSlots:/userID/:eventID/:slotID
router.route('/:userID/:eventID/:slotID')
    .get(function(req,res) {
        procedures.procGetSlotByUserAndTrip(req.params.userID, 
        req.params.eventID).then(function(greenTripUserSlot){
            res.send(greenTripUserSlot);
        }, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.sendStatus(500);

        })
    })
    .delete(function(req, res){
        procedures.procRemoveMe(req.params.slotID).then(function(){
            res.sendStatus(204);
        }, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
        });
    })
```

Backend Procedures:

```
exports.procGetSlotByUserAndTrip = function(userID, eventID) {
    return db.fnRow('procGetSlotByUserAndTrip', [userID, eventID])
}

exports.procRemoveMe = function(slotID) {
    return db.fnEmpty('procRemoveMe', [slotID])
```

SQL Stored Procedure for Get:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`CharleyHannah`@`localhost` PROCEDURE 
`procGetSlotByUserAndTrip`(pUserId INT, pEventId INT)
BEGIN
SELECT * 
FROM userEvents u
WHERE u.userID = pUserId & u.eventID = pEventId;
END
```

SQL Stored Procedure for delete:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`CharleyHannah`@`localhost` PROCEDURE 
`procRemoveMe`(pSlotId int)
BEGIN
DELETE
FROM userEvents 
WHERE id = pSlotId; 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `GreenTripFilledSlotsFactory.get(data);` returns a promise. You can write something like that:

```
var _promise = GreenTripFilledSlotsFactory.get(data);
_promise.then(function(res) {
   $scope.mySlot = res;
   console.log($scope.mySlot.id);   //should display your value now
});
```

In the `res` Variable your object is stored.

Comment: so this results in an error saying getMySlot is not a function:

     `var getMySlot = GreenTripFilledSlotsFactory.get(data); 
      getMySlot.then(function(res){
                $scope.mySlot = res;
       });`

AND this results in an error saying getMySlot.then is not a function:

    `var getMySlot = function(){
                GreenTripFilledSlotsFactory.get(data) 
            }; 
            getMySlot().then(function(res){
                $scope.mySlot = res;
            });`

Comment: i updated the original post to include more of the code i'm using

Comment: i thought my problem was an async vs sync issue:
I rewrote the $scope.removeMe function to be a chain of promises.

However i am still having the same issues of $scope.mySlot.id being undefined and the delete request failing.

Answer (score 0):

You assign userToRemove outside the promise then and it's executed before $scope.ME assingning.

Comment: i'm successfully getting me.id (which is the user's id in the user table).

I'm then passing that along to successfully get the row where both userID AND tripID exist in a Join table.
This is showing up in the console.log for $scope.mySlot HOWEVER i cannot access the data in $scope.mySlot to use the id of that row in the join table in the delete request

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the factories, I had success in just using $http.get and $http.delete requests:

```
 $scope.removeMe = function() {                                      
    var shouldRemove = confirm('Remove you from this field trip?');
    if (shouldRemove) {
        var data = null;
        UserService.me().then(function(me){
            var data = {eventID: tripID, userID: me.id}
            console.log(data);

            return data;
        }).then (function(data){ 

           var mySlot = $http.get('/api/GreenTripSlots/' + data.eventID + '/' + data.userID);
           console.log(mySlot);

           return mySlot;
        }).then (function(mySlot) {

            var slotToDelete = mySlot.data;
            console.log(slotToDelete);
            console.log(slotToDelete.id)

            return slotToDelete;
        }).then (function(slotToDelete){
            var slotID = slotToDelete.id;
            $http.delete('/api/GreenTripSlots/delete/' + slotID);
            console.log('deleted successfully')     
            $route.reload();
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        })
    }   
};
```

}])